# Change blade template variable

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.5

I've read many articles about how to pass variables and assigning variables in a blade template, but my question is: 
How to change a variable value based on ajax response? Is it possible?

Comment: I have modified my answer so you can actually change the variable, once is initialized by the controller :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a hidden input in your template which first is initialized from controller:

```
<input class="input" id="inputHidden" 
name="inputHidden" 
value="{{$variableName}}" hidden>
```

where `$variableName` is the variable sent by te controller along with the view.

after that change the value returned on ajax success branch to this hidden input like that:

```
$('#inputHidden').attr('value',returnedValueByAjax)
```